# Accessing Strings in other methods created by JOptionPane?

Tags: java, string, variables, methods, joptionpane

I'm trying to use a string created by JOptionPane in another JOptionPane. I tried making the string global. Am I doing this correctly?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Dialogue
{
    public static String reason = "";
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ask();
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You're here because: " + reason);
}

public static void ask()
{
    String reason = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Why are you here?");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this statement:

```
String reason = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Why are you here?");
```

You're creating a new `String`. So the global variable and this one aren't referencing the same `String`.

Do it like this:

```
reason = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Why are you here?");
```

This way you're using the global variable, as you want.

EDIT:
I guess that you don't want an user input after asking why he's there, so I guess you would like to switch this:

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You're here because: " + reason);
```

to this

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You're here because: " + reason);
```

This way, it just gives an information, and doesn't wait for an user input.

Comment: Thank you. The reason I am waiting for an input is because I do not know how to continue after a message dialog. Would I just request another input after?

Answer (score 1):

remove `String` from `ask` method (as by doing so you are creating a new local variable `reason` )

keep it as

```
reason = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Why are you here?");
```

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

the string `reason` is declarted as global and static variable, so ther is no need to redelrated is `ask ()` method

```
public class Dialogue
{
    public static String reason = "";
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ask();
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You're here because: " + reason);
}

public static void ask()
{
     reason = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Why are you here?");
}
}
```

[image]  [image]